# How to make redirect inside component in React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to make redirect inside component in React router? I'm using react-rouer

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash';
import FavoriteItem from '../components/FavoriteItem'

const FavoritesList = ({list}) => {

    let transitionToItem = ({id}) => {
        // make transition to `/details/${id}`
    };

    return (
        <ul className="list-group favorites-list">
            <FavoriteItem onFavoriteClick={ () => { transitionToItem(item); } } key={item.id} item={item}/>
        </ul>
    );
};


export default FavoritesList
```

Route:

```
<Route path="details/:item" name="details" component={DetailsPage}/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the preferred way to do this would be to wrap whatever element you're clicking on in a react-router `Link` element and let the router handle everything.

```
<Link to=`/details/${item_id}`>Click me!</Link>
```

If you definitely want to take your approach, import the `browserHistory` module from react-router into your component and push the new URL right onto it.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
let transitionToItem = ({id}) => {
  browserHistory.push(`/details/${id}`);
};
```